# Change scale of charts in Nivo Rocks in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I change scale of Nivo Rocks chart, look at this image:
[image: Nivo rocks]
On the y-axis it should show more than 893 but it shows 800 and ignores the 93 points! In some cases it works now but in others it doesn't, but our QA said it should work anyway :(

so, any ideas to help me make it more sense?

this is my code:

```
const ValueAtStack = () => {
    const { callData, data, loading } = useNegotiationGlanceStackValue();
    const params = useParams<any>();
    const { data: dataNegotiation } = useNegotiation(params.id);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (params.id) callData({ negotiationId: params.id });
    }, [params.id]);

    const colors = [
        ThemeColors().blueDark1,
        ...(data?.data ? data?.data?.map(() => ThemeColors().blue) : []),
    ];

    return (
        <Item
            icon={<DollarOutlined />}
            title={t("Saving")}
            loading={loading}
            empty={data?.data?.length === 0 || !data?.data}
            emptyDescription={t("Please add some negotiation rounds in Result Tracker")}
            emptyExtra={
                <CustomButton
                    href={`/pipelines/fact-sheet/${params.id}/lead-negotiation/results-tracker`}>
                    {t("Results Tracker")}
                </CustomButton>
            }>
            <div className={classes.description}>
                <Currency replace={dataNegotiation?.currencyId} />
                {t(`'${data?.unit}`)}
            </div>
            <div
                className={classes.content}
                style={{
                    height: 300,
                    width: window.innerWidth - 300,
                }}>
                {data && (
                    <ResponsiveBar
                        data={[data.target, ...data?.data]}
                        keys={["Latest offer"]}
                        indexBy="date"
                        margin={{ top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
                        padding={0.3}
                        colors={colors}
                        colorBy={"indexValue"}
                        valueScale={{ type: "linear" }}
                        indexScale={{ type: "band", round: true }}
                        defs={[
                            {
                                id: "dots",
                                type: "patternDots",
                                background: "inherit",
                                color: "#38bcb2",
                                size: 4,
                                padding: 1,
                                stagger: true,
                            },
                            {
                                id: "lines",
                                type: "patternLines",
                                background: "inherit",
                                color: "#eed312",
                                rotation: -45,
                                lineWidth: 6,
                                spacing: 10,
                            },
                        ]}
                        borderColor={{
                            from: "color",
                            modifiers: [["darker", 1.6]],
                        }}
                        axisTop={null}
                        axisRight={null}
                        axisBottom={{
                            tickSize: 5,
                            tickPadding: 5,
                            tickRotation: data.length > 5 ? 45 : 0,
                            legendPosition: "middle",
                            legendOffset: 32,
                        }}
                        axisLeft={{
                            tickSize: 5,
                            tickPadding: 5,
                            tickRotation: 0,
                            legendPosition: "middle",
                            legendOffset: -40,
                        }}
                        labelSkipWidth={12}
                        labelSkipHeight={12}
                        labelTextColor={{
                            from: "color",
                            modifiers: [["darker", 1.6]],
                        }}
                        role="application"
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        </Item>
    );
};

export default ValueAtStack;
```

a minimal data:

```
{
    date: "2023-03-23T12:37:32.835",
    "Latest offer": 893,
}
```

Comment: _In some cases it works now but in others it doesn't_. What does that mean? Have you investigated which are those cases?

Comment: Yes, for example, when the point is 20, it shows correctly

Comment: Can you post minimal reproducible example with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use maxValue option. It looks like it is with 100 step size.

```
maxValue={1000}
```

This will always have 1000 as max count. One solution to make it dynamic is you will need to loop through your data and get the max point. Then you add 100 to it and set this as maxValue.

In your case 893 is max.
You add 100 to it. maxValue={993}.
So Y axis will show 900 point in the top.

Hope this helps.